# How to generate Python XHR Request in requests.post()

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get info from a website using AJAX. The [Website](https://www.beautyfresh.com/product/fragrance/men/perfume-fragrance/women/perfume-men/fragrance/perfume/jo-malone-orange-blossom-cologne) showing different size for perfume and basically, the price would change when selecting different size.
I  checked chrome Network Tab and found it's a XHR request, but looking at the request head I have no idea how to generate the same headers and data with the Requests package.

This is how my code currently looks like:

```
import requests    
url = "https://www.beautyfresh.com/uc_aac"
session = requests.Session()
data = {"attributes[Size]":"100ml"} # I want to get the price for 100ml
headers = {"Referer": "https://www.beautyfresh.com/product/fragrance/men/perfume-fragrance/women/perfume-men/fragrance/perfume/jo-malone-orange-blossom-cologne",}
r = session.post(url,headers=headers,data=data)
print(r.text)
```

The **General** information under Chrome Network tab is

```
Request URL: https://www.beautyfresh.com/uc_aac
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 103.255.250.100:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

The **Response Headers** is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Fri, 18 Dec 2020 02:01:05 GMT
expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
x-site: beautyfresh
x-url: /uc_aac
last-modified: Fri, 18 Dec 2020 02:01:05 GMT
x-backend-server: web4
content-type: application/json
x-varnish: 700512226
age: 0
via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0)
x-cache: MISS
cache-control: Cache-Control: store, no-cache, must-revalidate
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 2193
```

The **Request Headers** is

```
POST /uc_aac HTTP/1.1
Host: www.beautyfresh.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 164
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: https://www.beautyfresh.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://www.beautyfresh.com/product/fragrance/men/perfume-fragrance/women/perfume-men/fragrance/perfume/jo-malone-orange-blossom-cologne
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9
Cookie: has_js=1; SESSc5f2026dce40de323b60d32130e6ce0b=n7tr5e2fsragf1js6garc6u06n; _ga=GA1.2.959938064.1608216963; _gid=GA1.2.1979056032.1608216963; _v1EmaticSolutionsUTMData=%7B%22utm_source%22%3A%22%22%2C%22utm_medium%22%3A%22%22%2C%22utm_campaign%22%3A%22%22%7D; _fbp=fb.1.1608216963288.1600789170; _v1EmaticSolutionsBye=%7B%2228732%22%3A%7B%2230038%22%3A%7B%22dont_show_till%22%3A%222020-12-20%22%2C%22loop%22%3A1%7D%7D%2C%2228739%22%3A%7B%2230045%22%3A%7B%22dont_show_till%22%3A%222020-12-20%22%2C%22loop%22%3A1%7D%7D%7D; _v1EmaticSolutionsEI=%7B%22c_28739_1%22%3A%5B1%2C1608216997180%2C33181%5D%2C%22c_28732_2%22%3A%5B1%2C1608216969616%2C0%5D%7D; _v1EmaticSolutions=%5B%22fc5d18b3-4077-11eb-970e-0242ac160003%22%2C1608217230870%2C%5B%22IMG%22%2C%22%22%2C1%2C%22glasshouse_fragrances_amalfi_coast_sea_candle_350gr.jpg%22%5D%5D; __atuvc=8%7C51; __atuvs=5fdc0d5961186ea4000; _gat=1; _dc_gtm_UA-63339192-1=1
```

And **Form Data** shows:

```
attributes%5BSize%5D=100ml&nid=2905&qty=1&form_build_id=form-991e88780c30fdf883375a36a986b550&form_id=uc_product_add_to_cart_form_2905&product-nid=2905&aac_nid=2905
```

I don't actually know how to construct my request so it can be successfully posted to the server the get the proper response. It should return the price for "100ml", but currently my code get nothing.

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some information in your `data`. To receive a response, try adding `"aac_nid": "2905"` to your `data` when sending the `post` request:

```
import requests


headers = {
    "Referer": "https://www.beautyfresh.com/product/fragrance/men/perfume-fragrance/women/perfume-men/fragrance/perfume/jo-malone-orange-blossom-cologne",
}

data = {"attributes[Size]": "30ml", "aac_nid": "2905"}

response = requests.post(
    "https://www.beautyfresh.com/uc_aac", headers=headers, data=data
)
```

```
>>> print(response.content)
b'{"nid":"2905","model":"690251006564","replacements":{"sellprice":"<div class=\\"product-info sellprice\\"><div class=\'retail_price\'>City Price: <div class=\'product-info retail_price\'><span class=\'uc-price\'>S$110.00<\\/span><\\/div><\\/div>\\r\\n                <div class=\'promoprice\'>Our Price: <div class=\'product-info sellprice1\'><span class=\'uc-price\'>S$89.00<\\/span><\\/div><\\/div><\\/div>","model":"<div class=\\"model\\"><span class=\\"label\\">Product Code: <\\/span>690251006564<\\/div>"},"form":"<form action=\\"\\/uc_aac\\"  accept-charset=\\"UTF-8\\" method=\\"post\\" id=\\"uc-product-add-to-cart-form\\" class=\\" uc-aac-cart\\">\\n<div><div class=\'attributes\'><div class=\\"form-item\\" id=\\"edit-attributes-Size-wrapper\\">\\n <label for=\\"edit-attributes-Size\\">Size <span class=\\"form-required\\" title=\\"This field is required.\\">*<\\/span><\\/label>\\n <select name=\\"attributes[Size]\\" class=\\"form-select required chosen-widget\\" data-name=\\"Size\\" id=\\"edit-attributes-Size\\" ><option value=\\"30ml\\" selected=\\"selected\\">30ml<\\/option><option value=\\"100ml\\">100ml<\\/option><\\/select>\\n<\\/div>\\n<\\/div><input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"nid\\" id=\\"edit-nid\\" value=\\"2905\\"  \\/>\\n<div class=\\"form-item\\" id=\\"edit-qty-wrapper\\">\\n <label for=\\"edit-qty\\">Qty <\\/label>\\n <input type=\\"text\\" maxlength=\\"3\\" name=\\"qty\\" id=\\"edit-qty\\" size=\\"5\\" value=\\"1\\" class=\\"form-text textfield\\" \\/>\\n<\\/div>\\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"form_build_id\\" id=\\"form-b7adf002178f04ed96377894057352a2\\" value=\\"form-b7adf002178f04ed96377894057352a2\\"  \\/>\\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"form_id\\" id=\\"edit-uc-product-add-to-cart-form\\" value=\\"uc_product_add_to_cart_form\\"  \\/>\\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"aac_nid\\" id=\\"edit-aac-nid\\" value=\\"2905\\"  \\/>\\n<div class=\'leadtime_message\' style=\'margin-bottom:1em;\'><p>Delivers in 1-3 working days<\\/p><\\/div><input type=\\"submit\\" name=\\"op\\" id=\\"edit-submit-2905\\" value=\\"Add to Cart\\"  class=\\"notranslate form-submit node-add-to-cart primary\\" \\/>\\n\\n<\\/div><\\/form>\\n"}'
```

To get the price, try searching for it with the help of the built-in [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (regex) module:

```
import re

prices = re.findall(r"'uc-price\\'>S(\$\d.*?)<", str(response.content))

print("Original Price:", prices[0])
print("Our Price:", prices[1])
```

Output:

```
Original Price: $110.00
Our Price: $89.00
```